# Sorting a list of string using a custom order stored in another list

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I have a list with 2 or 3 character strings with the last character being the same.

`example_list = ['h1','ee1','hi1','ol1','b1','ol1','b1']`

is there any way to sort this list using the order of another list.

`order_list = ['ee','hi','h','b','ol']`

So the answer should be something like `example_list.sort(use_order_of=order_list)`

Which should produce an output like `['ee1','hi1','h1','b1','b1','ol1','ol1']`

I have found other questions on StackOverflow but I am still unable find a answer with a good explanation.

Comment: And what if an element is not in `order_list`, e.g. the first element in `example_list`: `h1`?

Comment: What is the desired output for your example?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The `order_list` should in theory contain every single element in `example_list`.

Comment: desired output would be `['ee1','hi1','h1','b1','b1','ol1','ol1']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build an `order_map` that maps the prefixes to their sorting key, and then use that map for the key when calling `sorted`:

```
example_list = ['h1','ee1','hi1','ol1','b1','ol1','b1']
order_list = ['ee','hi','h','b','ol']
order_map = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(order_list)}
sorted(example_list, key=lambda x: order_map[x[:-1]])
```

This has an advantage over calling `order_list.index` for each element, as fetching elements from the dictionary is fast.

You can also make it work with elements that are missing from the `order_list` by using `dict.get` with a default value. If the default value is small (e.g. `-1`) then the values that don't appear in `order_list` will be put at the front of the sorted list. If the default value is large (e.g. `float('inf')`) then the values that don't appear in `order_list` will be put at the back of the sorted list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Can converting to a dict really make a difference in a short list. Because you would still have to go through the list for `order_map = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(order_list)}`

Comment: @DeeraWijesundara When you use `order_list.index` in your `sorted` key function, it gets called for every element, and it traverses `order_list` each time it is called, so the solution has a time complexity of O(n^2). Building the `order_map` dictionary takes one pass of `order_list`, and subsequent lookups in it in the `sorted` key function are each O(1), thereby making the solution have a time complexity of O(n). The difference between an O(n) and O(n^2) solution may not be significant for a small n, but given that the dictionary approach is hardly any more complicated it should be preferred

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted` with `key` using until the last string of each element in `example_list`:

```
sorted(example_list, key=lambda x: order_list.index(x[:-1]))
```

Ourput:

```
['ee1', 'hi1', 'h1', 'b1', 'b1', 'ol1', 'ol1']
```

Note that this assumes all element in `example_list` without the last character is in `order_list`

Comment: `.index` has `O(N)` time complexity. Make this solution `O(N^2)`. You could use some extra space `mapping = mapping = dict(zip(order_list, range(len(order_list))))` then `key = lambda x: mapping[x[:-1]]`.

Comment: @Ch3steR I'm aware of the complexity, but when the inputs are quite short, I think the simplicity comes before efficiency (purely my preference tho). In any case, @Will Da Silva's answer well demonstrates how to use `dict` for this purpose.

Comment: @Chris I never said you don't know. It was just a comment for future readers about the time complexity. Yes, when inputs are short it doesn't matter. My comment is for all the future readers who might use this solution without knowing the implications.

Comment: @Ch3steR Perhaps I should have mentioned about the simplicity vs efficiency in the first place :P But thank you for pointing out ;)

Answer (score -1):

Something like this? It has the advantage of handling duplicates.

```
sorted_list = [
    i
    for i, _
    in sorted(zip(example_list, order_list), key=lambda x: x[1])
]
```